# Cloud Functions for Firebase - .once('value') returning nothing

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I just started using Cloud Functions for Firebase. I'm stuck on retrieving data from the database.

I'm using `.once('value')` on a Firebase reference to convert it into a promise, but every time I run the function with Postman I get this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:725:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:256:15)
at Timeout.req.functionTimeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/supervisor/supervisor.js:192:14)
at ontimeout (timers.js:380:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:244:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

Here is the first function which calls for the function to get that data:

```
exports.userPlaylistStatus = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
     const userId = request.body.userId;
     // Wait to get the user reference
     const userRef = await buildUserRef(userId);
     response.send(userRef);
});
```

Here is the function I'm using `.once('value')` in. The promise is never returning a value. Even when I put a `console.log('hi')` inside the `.then()`, it is never logged.

```
async function buildUserRef(_userId: string) {
return await admin.database().ref(`/users/${_userId}`).once('value').then(
    // this would return the user reference but I have it as .val() for now
    res => {return res.val();},
    err => {console.log(err)}
);
}
```

Comment: Have you run `initializeApp`?
`admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`

Comment: @sketchthat yeah I have. I ended up being able to fix it but I had to download the credentials file from the firebase console and then import as my credential.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, it should be able to get the config from the `functions.config().firebase` call.